# Important polynomial identities?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I've learnt that there is $x^n-y^n$ and $x^n-1$ but are there any more I should learn for aiding with factorization?

Also if you have a series such as $s_n = a + ar + ar^2 + ar^3 + ... + ar^{n-1}$ if we say that n = 2, are we finding the sum of all the terms UP TO the 2nd term? Likewise if n = n, we are finding the sum of all the terms up to the nth term?
Thanks

Comment: Here's a useful one: If $n=ab$, then
$$\begin{align} t^{n-1}+t^{n-2}+\ldots +t+1&=t^{ab-1}+t^{ab-2}+\ldots +t+1\\&=(t^{a-1}+t^{a-2}+\ldots +t+1)(t^{(b-1)a}+t^{(b-2)a}+\ldots +t^a+1) \end{align}$$

Answer (score 0):

The entries in Pascal's Triangle are worth recognizing, at least the first several rows' worth for polynomial factorization.

For a series, you have specified

$$s_n=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}ar^i=\sum_{i=1}^nar^{i-1}$$

which is a series having $n$ terms, so "yes, it does go up to the $n$th term" but "no, it does not include $ar^n$".  For $n=2$ we would have $s_2=a+ar=ar^0+ar^1$, which is a $2$-term series.

Comment: awesome, and what about $x^n +y^n$?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question, but for odd $n$ you have $x^n+y^n=(x+y)\sum_{i=0}^n(-1)^ix^iy^{n-i}$...

Comment: yeah how would you factorize $x^n + y^n$? Why does it only work for odd n only and could you explain the summation?